# java.lang.ClassCastException after getBoolean

Tags: java, android

I received this crash report in my Google Play Console which I do not experience in my own device.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2594)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2685)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:188)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1530)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:210)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5833)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1113)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:879)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean (SharedPreferencesImpl.java:260)
  at .Dictionary.onCreate (Dictionary.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6177)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1112)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2541)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2685)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:188)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1530)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:210)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5833)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1113)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:879)
```

This is part of my `onCreate` in `Dictionary.java` which I suspect is the source of problem. However, I myself do not face any problem. I don't understand why it crash on some devices.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean mCoinCount = settings.getBoolean("mCoinCount", false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        if (mCoinCount) {
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES, ICONS, NAME, this);
        } else {
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(NTITLES, NICONS, NAME, this);
        }
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(Dictionary.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Previously I did not `getBoolean` from `SharedPreferences`. So I do not face this crash.

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES, ICONS, NAME, this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(Dictionary.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: If there's a ClassCastException it means the stored value for that key is not a boolean on that device for some reason. `mCoinCount` suggests an integer value. Did it used to be one?

Comment: Please ignore the "count" word. I'm sure `mCoinCount` is a `boolean` and never been used.

Comment: @dustytrash that's why there's a def value return.

Comment: Then that user probably has root and is attempting to "cheat" your (I'm assuming) game by modifying the SharedPreferences of the app. Since you named it `Count` they probably think it's an integer. Ignore it.

Comment: Hit `CTRL+SHIFT+F` and search for `"mCoinCount"` and see what places you were putting a value using this key. Also have any OTHER previous versions of this app had some code that was removed or changed that would put a value in shared prefs using this key?

Comment: @Vucko, yes I did the CTRL + SHIFT +F. However in my previous version, I put this `mCoinCount` in the other activity. I added `mCoinCount` in current activity.

Comment: Doesn't matter which activity it is in, `SharedPreferences` are shared throughout the app (if you're using the same key for getting them). Post relevant code where that is being used

Comment: I published an app update which reverted back my code to the previous version (the last piece of code as posted above). Now this crash gone.